# How to make your GWT application plug-able?

Tags: gwt, plugins

I am writing (with my team) an GWT application, which parses and represent some domain specific language - for example, plays media presentation with text, video and UI controls. So the application has a set of components: ones - for holding model, ones - for control routines (controllers), and of course we have classes for View.

Now we have a problem - make it all plug-able, in the sense of:

- should be one **core** plugin, which make all common stuff. This coer block must be an JavaScript file (one for every permutation)
- should be ability to **extend** core classes, write custom ones - and compile it to separate JS file (one for every permutation)

Every plugin must registers (export it's classes etc) itself to the core platform, so it could be used.

Problems:

1. How to **compile** the custom stuff
   separately ?
2. How to **load** plugins ?

For the **second** one **problem** i've found http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/, that exports GWT classes to outer world, so they could be invoked from pure JS.

Also I have an idea to create **new module** for new plugin, so it will be compiled to separate file (**first problem**).

Have you an experience of building such architecture, have you some best practices in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experimented with this same question since GWT 1.5 and every time I come up with a more elegant solution they change the linker and break it.  The only way that I have come up with that would work independent of linker design is to do exactly what you are talking about and create a new module for ever plug-in.  Then use GWT exporter to create an abstract class that plugins must extend that would have an abstract method that would take the root element of the plugin passed to it by the core and populate it.  The issue with this method is all plug-in modules must be added to the DOM on the initial load of the page because since 2.0 the iFrame linker relies on a page load event so dynamically added modules wont fully load.  So because of this you will want to have the exported population method wrapped in runAsync so that you aren't downloading modules till you use them.

Edit:

Here is a rough example of what I am talking about. Please be aware that I haven't done any GWT in a couple years and there may be a better way of doing this by now.

```
public final class PluginManager
{
    public static final PluginManager INSTANCE = new PluginManager();

    private PluginManager()
    {
    }

    private static native void loadPlugin( AbstractPlugin plugin )
    /*-{
        if (!$wnd.Plugins) {
            $wnd.Plugins = {};
        }
        var name = plugin.@com.example.PluginManager.AbstractPlugin::getName()();
        $wnd.Plugins[name] = $entry(plugin.@com.example.PluginManager.AbstractPlugin::load(Ljava/lang/String;));
    }-*/;

    private static native void unloadPlugin( AbstractPlugin plugin )
    /*-{
        if ($wnd.Plugins) {
            var name = plugin.@com.example.PluginManager.AbstractPlugin::getName()();
            delete $wnd.Plugins[name];
        }
    }-*/;

    private static native JsArrayString getPlugins()
    /*-{
        if ($wnd.Plugins) {
            return Object.keys($wnd.Plugins);
        }
        return undefined;
    }-*/;

    public static abstract class AbstractPlugin implements EntryPoint
    {
        @Override
        public final void onModuleLoad()
        {
            PluginManager.INSTANCE.loadPlugin( this );
        }

        protected final void unload()
        {
            PluginManager.INSTANCE.unloadPlugin( this );
        }

        protected abstract String getName();

        protected abstract void load( String rootPanelId );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh... Thank you. For this two hours, since I post a question, I've made some solution. As you said, I've created Core module and interface IPlugin, that all plugins should implement. Then I've added to html file, I'm laoding, both modules initialization. 

Although this isn't final solution, I think this is good start.

Comment: `Then use GWT exporter to create an abstract class that plugins must extend that would have an abstract method that would take the root element of the plugin passed to it by the core and populate it. ` Can you please go into details on this? are you saying that you would export a GWT java class to javascript (using gwt exporter), and then the plugin module should (maybe from a JSNI native method) extend and implement the given abstract class?

Comment: There would be something like a PluginManager that would expose a registration method through the exporter (this is actually really simple through JSNI and may not be necessary to add the GWT Exporter dependency). The AbstractPlugin will also be an entry point that will register itself with the PluginManager (through JSNI/Exporter). AbstractPlugin will also expose a inject method that takes in an element ID to use as the root element to instantiate an instance of the plugin. I will add to my answer.