# How do I add support for plugins to a web application in GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-applications, plugins

I'm making a note taking application and I want to support plugins so that the user can get extra features by adding plugins from 3rd party developers. The only problem is that I don't know how to do this in GWT or javaScript. I'm willing to do it in javaScript but I'd prefer to do it in GWT. I'd like it to work like this:
the 3rd party developer makes the plugin and the plugin would implement a interface I made.
They upload the code to my server
The user selects the plugins they want
Whenever the user goes to my app those plugins will be there so they can use them.
I know that something like this is possible because google wave had many different types of extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately GWT won't help you in plugins - by principle, GWT assume it has all the sources needed by application. So to achieve it, you you need to go down to JSNI to discover and load plugins. Here are more details on that: [How to make your GWT application plug-able?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818318/how-to-make-your-gwt-application-plug-able)

I would also suggest looking into Apache Wave source (former Google Wave), which you also referred in your question. http://incubator.apache.org/wave/