# How to avoid downloading the same js files, images, css etcetera in GWT

Tags: caching, gwt, download

I'm making a GWT app with multiple modules. My app has plugins(extensions) which means that I have to get the modules at runtime and third party developers need to upload their plugins at runtime. go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711776/how-do-i-add-support-for-plugins-to-a-web-application-in-gwt) for more context. I don't know what modules I'll get until runtime. As far as I know you can't inherit a new module at runtime outside of telling the server to change the gwt.xml file to inherit the right module and recompiling at runtime which would be unacceptably slow. [GWT warned against this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) and rightly so. I've had a lot of issues. One of which is that the modules all share some code and I'm afraid that each plugin will get that code. This would be very inefficient. How can I make this more efficient? Is there a better way to get plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Code Splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) is for.

You can split each of your optional modules into a code fragment and let the compiler do its magic. The compiler will see which code fragments share the same code, and it may decide that it's more efficient to merge these fragments into a single fragment rather than keep them separate. Or it may move some code into a fragment that loads last - after the initial fragment and the ones your users need immediately.

In my experience, it's hard to improve significantly by hand compared to what a compiler would do for you automatically. The only optimization that I would suggest is playing around with the maximum number of fragments (i.e. telling the compiler how aggressive it should be in merging similar fragments) - the results would be slightly different and you can choose the best option based on your expected app usage patterns.

Comment: I should have said that I third party developers need to upload plugins. I edited the question so that it says that now. I don't think that's possible since the code is split at compile time. Unfortunately, the developers will upload their plugins after compile time.

Comment: If these "plugins" are outside of your control, they are just separate applications. It's not clear then, what you are asking. You can't optimize apps that are not yours and come from different developers. The best you can do is tell your server to make those assets (JS, CSS, etc.) cacheable, but this has nothing to do with GWT.

Comment: If I could put the shared code in a separate js file then I could cache it but GWT puts everything in one line rather than separate files. I think they do this to make the download faster.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. If you cannot compile, why does it matter what GWT does or does not? GWT is a compiler.

Comment: If this was in JavaScript this wouldn't be an issue. It's very easy to accidentally get j query twice. Fortunately, the browser takes care of this by not downloading the same coffee twice if it sees the same script tag twice. Meanwhile GWT doesn't use the script tag. That prevents the browser from doing this for us

Comment: GWT does use the script tag, and it does not download the same code twice if you use code splitting. Moreover, you can include third-party JS code in your host page, or inject it at runtime, just as you would do with JavaScript. No differences here.